# Pydantic | Serialise and deserialise

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic

Let's say I have the following BaseModel

```
class A(BaseModel):
    Capacity: float
    Created: datetime


@field_validator('Created', mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def date_type_conversion(cls, value: str, info: FieldValidationInfo) -> datetime:
        assert isinstance(value, str), info.field_name + " must be date as str 'dd-MMM-yy'"
        return datetime.strptime(value, "%d-%b-%y")

    @field_validator('Capacity', mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def trimming_string(cls, value: str, info: FieldValidationInfo) -> str:
        return value.strip()
```

I have a simple test case as follows

```
import json
import unittest
import dataclasses

from pydantic import ValidationError, parse_obj_as

from models import A
from models.AllOptional import partial_model




class TestA(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_Optional(self):
        a_json = {"Capacity": "20.20","Created": "02-Jun-10"}
        a_model = partial_model(A.A)
        try:
            a_data = a_model(**a_json)
            print(a_data) # works

            d2 = a_data.model_dump_json()
            print(d2) # float is number, date is string

            d3 = a_model.parse_raw(d2)
            print(d3) # here, float validation and date validation is breaking

        except ValidationError as exc:
            print(exc)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

My Use case:

I am trying to consume a message from Kafka(a_data), do some validations(type checking, type conversion, name changes for the fields), then send that to Kafka Back. Next app will read this (validated) data that is in the second Kafka topic and try to use the same model to validate it.

Python 3.x and pydantic 2.4

Since I am using pydantic for the first time, is my understanding correct. And how could I handle this?

Thanks for your help.